# With python How do i get the date by quarter

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

Using either python, pandas or dateutil, how do I get last friday of the three month period, where the period end could be april. Since I am targeting a "focal date", which is last friday of the months with a three month lead time, I may need to extend leadtime  to six months.

```
SourceDate, Q1, Q2, Q3

2013-Jun-26 2013-Sep-20 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-25 2013-Sep-20 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-24 **2013-Sep-20** 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
**2013-Jun-21** **2013-Jun-21** 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-20 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-19 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-18 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-17 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-14 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-13 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-12 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-11 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-10 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-07 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-06 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-05 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-04 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-Jun-03 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-31 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-30 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-29 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-28 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-24 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-23 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-22 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-21 2013-Jun-21 2013-Aug-16 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-20 2013-Jun-21 **2013-Aug-16** 2013-Jul-19
**2013-May-17** 2013-Jun-21 **2013-May-17** 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-16 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-15 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-14 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-13 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-10 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-09 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-08 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-07 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-06 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-03 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-02 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-May-01 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-30 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-29 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-26 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-25 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-24 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-23 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Jul-19
2013-Apr-22 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 **2013-Jul-19**
**2013-Apr-19** 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 **2013-Apr-19**
2013-Apr-18 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-17 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-16 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-15 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-12 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-11 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-10 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
2013-Apr-09 2013-Jun-21 2013-May-17 2013-Apr-19
```

I have tried pandas `BMonthEnd` and `BQuarterEnd` with `WeekOfMonth(weekday = 4, week =2)`, I cant the rolling part.

Edit:

```
>>>d = dt.datetime(2013, 5, 15)
>>>list(rrule(MONTHLY, count=5, byweekday=FR, bysetpos=3,dtstart =d ))
[datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from dateutil.rrule import *
>>> list(rrule(MONTHLY, count=3, byweekday=FR, bysetpos=-1))
[datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 26, 22, 4, 20),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 30, 22, 4, 20),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 27, 22, 4, 20)]
```

---

```
>>> list(rrule(MONTHLY, count=12, byweekday=FR, bysetpos=-1))[::3]
[datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 26, 22, 15, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 25, 22, 15, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 22, 15, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 22, 15, 14)]
```

[rrule](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57)

Comment: Which now is the last Friday of a quarter (three-month period) the OP asks for?

Comment: @falsetru, the output is wrong for 5/15/2013, the first date should be jun/21 not 5/17.

Comment: @Merlin, Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. My answer/output does not contain 'jun/21' nor 'may/27'.

Comment: @Merlin, What is your expected output?

Comment: @falsetru, see question look at the third fridays, the first column should be three month based on (3,6,9,12) the second col three month based on the month (based on (2,5,8,11), third column 3 month based on months (1,4,7,10)... But not quarter end but third friday of the current period.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone like me ends up here from google, I found this approach easier to read:

```
d = datetime.now()
import pandas.tseries.offsets as offsets
print(d + offsets.QuarterEnd() - offsets.Week(weekday=4))
```

[pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#parametric-offsets)